# How to call a user defined mysql function in loopback's field array

Tags: loopback

Hi have a mysql function defined at database level, e.g. hasSubProductsForProduct(223), which gives me count of sub_products for given product id.

eg. following is query to get product details

```
Product.find(
       {
        fields : ['id','hasSubProductsForProduct(223) as sub_product_count'],
        where : {
             id : 7
        }
    },
    function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
```

But function doesn't returns sub_product_count field in response.

Can any one suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think loopback works like this. You need to tell a relation between products and sub-products. ie. for example `Products` hasMany `SubProducts`.

Then you can take the count by

1. first getting a product instance
2. Then using that instance, call the relation

   product_instace.subproducts.count()

Hope this helps.